# $window.location success message in Angular Js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, csv

I'm using `$window.location(url)` to download csv file directly from rest api.

i need to display success message,even though i'm using promises, the file is getting downloaded but i'm unable to show the success message.

```
function download() {
  getcsv().then(function(response) {
    if (response === 'success') {
      $scope.msg = 'success';
    }
  })
}
getCSV() {
  var defer = $q.defer;
  downloadCSV();
  return defer.promise;
}

function dowloadcsv() {
  $window.location(url);
}
```

Comment: Can we see the rest of your code, where you show type of message you are attempting to display?

Comment: `function download(){ 
getcsv().then(function(response){
if(response==='success')
{ $scope.msg='success';}
})
}
getCSV(){
var defer=$q.defer;
downloadCSV();
return defer.promise;
}
function dowloadcsv(){
$window.location(url);
}
`

Comment: first of all, you are not giving the promise a value to resolve to, so your then will never get hit. You can use `defer.resolve(value);` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#resolve

Comment: The other issue is that `location.url()` doesn't return a promise or anything it just returns `location`, so I don't know how what value you are planning on putting in the promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use $timeout service that returns a promise:

```
app.factory('downloadService', function($q, $window, $timeout) {
    return {
    download: function(url) {
        var defer = $q.defer();

        $timeout(function () {
            $window.location.href = url;

        }, 1000)
            .then(function () {
                defer.resolve('success');
            }, function () {
                defer.reject('error');
            });
        return defer.promise;
        }
    }
}
```

If the above code it's not an alternative, try to use $q.resolve inside your downloadcsv function.

Comment: One thing to note though is that by passing 1000 in to `$timeout` you are delaying the "download" by that many milliseconds (which maybe you want, idk). Also, the `$timeout` doesn't actually accomplish anything here because it will always return success in this example (this is because the promise in $timeout only gets rejected if you cancel it using https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout#cancel).